# Listview alternate row colour fails when views recycle happen

Tags: android, listview

I am having a listview and I have alternate row color change in my code. It works fine when i have small list. When the list size increases and due to views recyling it getting collapsed.How to solve this?
Below is my code:

```
   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.adapter_solist, null);
        if ( position % 2 == 1) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#add8e6"));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b0c4de"));
        }

        dbHelper.openReadableDatabase();
        sotran = dbHelper.getUdatedSOLineItem(strFlag);
        dbHelper.closeDatabase();
        if(sotran.size()!=0){
        for(int i=0;i<sotran.size();i++){
            int pos = Integer.parseInt(sotran.get(i).getRowid())-1;
            if(position==pos){
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
            }
        }
        }



        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.itmNum = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
        viewHolder.itmDesc = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
        viewHolder.itmQty = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvQty);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;

    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    holder.itmNum.setText(list.get(position).getItem());
    holder.itmDesc.setText(list.get(position).getDescrip());
    holder.itmQty.setText(list.get(position).getQtyord());

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Use tag instead of position, in your adapter set tag to your view and then compare the tag to get derided result.

Comment: @Abhishek I used this code: String strtag = convertView.getTag().toString();.. But it throws a error.

Comment: String strtag = convertView.getTag().toString(); why you are trying to get it as a string.

Comment: I am getting it in a string and converting as a integer to compare. if that not the way then how can I get the tag and compare it.

Comment: Pls update the question to include where is your `if(convertView == null){..}else{..}`.

Comment: @I_A_Mok. Please check my updated code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this code

```
if ( position % 2 == 1) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#add8e6"));
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b0c4de"));
    }

    dbHelper.openReadableDatabase();
    sotran = dbHelper.getUdatedSOLineItem(strFlag);
    dbHelper.closeDatabase();
    if(sotran.size()!=0){
    for(int i=0;i<sotran.size();i++){
        int pos = Integer.parseInt(sotran.get(i).getRowid())-1;
        if(position==pos){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
        }
    }
```

with only condition if convertView==null I think you should add the above code in else part also when convertView!=null

Answer (score 0):

Use setId for getting desire result like -

You need to do it as, First set tag to your view like **convertView.setId(position)** and then all you need to compare it as

```
if (containerView.getId() % 2 == 1) {
 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#add8e6"));
} else {
 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b0c4de"));
}
```

If this isn't working for you then it might because when you scroll down and up again the position that you already set in the view called again so it doesn't giving the desired results.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row1=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist_rows, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    return view;
}
```

Hope this helps. 
Happy Coding

Comment: Sorry am getting this error : operator % cannot be applied to java.lang.object int

Comment: Ohh, try by setting the id to view and compare it. As I edited my answer.

Comment: getId() works but not getting the expected result.. Collapsed same way as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Check if convertVeiw is null only then do your stuff otheriwise just set your as it was same in this manner your list will not collapsed. Check updated answer.

Comment: I already having  the condition (Convertview==null). It doesn't works. Sorry